# Evaluating Sigma Notations

Tags: calculus, summation

I've been having some troubling evaluating summations when the end value is not given. For example, when I am given:

(1)$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {(2i+1)}$$
and

(2)$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

I have no idea how I would solve equation 1 without given an end value. I suppose I would have to solve for n from equation 2 first, but I also wouldn't know when to end without having an end value.

Can someone please point me towards the right direction as to how I would solve equation 1?

This is my first post ever, sorry if I am not clear with my question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} {(2i+1)}=2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1$$

and

- $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \right)-n$
- $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 1=n-1$

Comment: Perhaps easier to reindex first, then break the sum up. That way it doesn't depend on your special treatment of the limits. In other words, $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i = \sum_{i=1}^na_{i-1}$

Comment: @MPW I've prefered this way to use the known relationship mentioned in the OP.Thanks!

Comment: Your hint helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @Shortytot Weel done, You are welcome. Bye!